# why am I getting javascript:unrecognized expression from this jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is my jQuery code:

```
$('.ajax_modal a').not('.popup').live('click', function(e){

//do something

 });
```

When I click on the anchor a.popup, I would expect nothing to happen:

```
<div class="ajax_modal">
<a class="popup">Should do nothing</div>
<a class="something">Should do something<a>
</div>
```

Instead I get the following error which is breaking my page:

**Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .ajax_modal a.not(.popup)**

Comment: FYI: Live is deprecated 1.7+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.live()` doesn't work well with chained traversal methods.

Change that to

```
$('.ajax_modal a:.not(.popup)')
```

Answer (score 1):

**1:** Tags are not being closed properly.

```
<div class="ajax_modal">
  <a class="popup">Should do nothing</div>
  <a class="something">Should do something<a>
</div>
```

should be:

```
<div class="ajax_modal">
  <a class="popup">Should do nothing</a> <!-- changed from </div> -->
  <a class="something">Should do something</a> <!-- changed from <a> -->
</div>
```

**2:** You are better off using **[`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) instead of `.not()`** as demonstrated below:

```
$('.ajax_modal a:not(".popup")').on('click', function(e){
   console.log(this);
});
```

**3:** Finally, `live` has been deprecated. So **use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind events**.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ChaseWest/buLTs/1/)**

Comment: While not() does accept a jquery object, it also accepts any jquery selector. Filter would be quite a long way round I feel. Using the :not pseudo-selector is definetly the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your "popup" hyperlink is closed with a  tag instead of an  tag. Similarly, the "something" hyperlink isn't being closed properly. Also worth noting: some browsers complain for not including the "href" attribute within hyperlink tags so at the very least add `href="#"` in them.